# Javascript: Passing Address of Array Element into Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, pointers

In FORTRAN and C++, the address of a specific array element can be passed into a function. For example, in the main routine, *WA1* is a work array of size 25 and *offset* is an integer variable that indicates the offset from the 0-index. Say *offset* is presently 6.

The declaration of the sub-routine might look like the following:

```
void Array_Manip1(double* WorkArray1){
. . .
```

When the sub-routine is called in the main program, the call might look like this:

```
Array_Manip1(&WA1[offset]);
```

By doing this, I can index *WorkArray1* within the sub-routine starting at the 0-index, but knowing it is actually WA1[6].

e.g. -

```
for (int i = 0; i < 19; ++i)
   WorkArray1[i] =  whatever computation is required.
```

To do this in Javascript, I suppose the full array could be passed in to the sub-routine, plus one more variable to hold the offset. And then within the sub-routine, the offset would have to be added to the array index value.

e. g. -

```
for (int i = 0; i < 19; ++i){
 WorkArray1[offset + i] =  whatever computation is required.
```

But now I am passing one more variable into the sub-routine, and have to add the offset to the array index each time through the loop.

Is there a better way to do this in Javascript?
Is there a way to imitate C++'s ability to pass the address of a specific array element into a function?

Comment: In managed-memory languages, the language is generally completely in control of the creation of references. So, **no**, you cannot do that.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way would be to splice the array and pass in a subarray from the current index on. That way you still have one reference, and everything stays clean.

But no, arrays in most higher level languages do not allow you to reference a single element and then get back to the array. It is dangerous for a number of reasons on those kinds of languages where the underlying data may not even be stored contiguously. JavaScript is no exception, and you can pass in an array and an index, or a subarray, but you can't pass in a reference to an element in the array and get back to the array after passing it in.

Comment: besides, JavaScript Arrays are just hash tables with integer keys and a few special behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

Tim's answer is correct. I just want to add something about the C-like [typed arrays](https://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/): they can be created as a view into an ArrayBuffer, in which case you could create a new view of the same buffer as the larger array but starting at an offset, and pass that, without duplicating the underlying data. Closest you can get to your pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of do what you want. And in fact, sometimes javascript can *only* do what you want. It all depends on what data the array contains.

In Javascript, the content of a variable may either be a value or a reference (pointer but without pointer arithmetic). But you have no choice in the matter. Numbers and strings are always values (there are exceptions but none of them apply when passing as function arguments) and everything else are always references.

So to get the behavior you want, simply use an object or array as your value holder instead of a string or number:

```
var ref_array = [ {value:1}, {value:2}, {value:3} ];

function increment (v_obj) {
    v_obj.value ++;
}

var ref = ref_array[1];
increment(ref);

// ref_array will now contain: [{value:1},{value:3},{value:3}]
```

It's not that simple though. While the object appears to be passed by reference, the reference is however copied when the function is called. What this means is that `ref` and `ref_array[1]` and `v_obj` are three separate variables that point to the same thing.

For example, this wouldn't work:

```
function replace (obj1, obj2) {
    obj1 = obj2;
}

replace(ref_array[1], {value:9});

// ref_array is still: [{value:1},{value:3},{value:3}]
```

That's because, while `obj1` in the function above points to the same object as `ref_array[1]`, it is not really a pointer to `ref_array[1]` but a separate variable. In C, this would be something like `obj1 = &ref_array[1]`. So passing an argument passes a copy of the pointer but not the pointer itself.

Comment: Note that what I mean by use array or object is that this trick can also be done with `[[1],[2],[3]]` and the function would simply access it as `v_obj[0]`

Comment: This in no way answers his question about passing in pointers to specific indexes in the array. Really good description of how js handles byref/byval though

Comment: @Tim: It answers his question "is there a way to imitate C++'s ability...". And the answer is yes, there is. But it's hacky.

Comment: He wants to pass in a pointer to an element in the array, and then go on to other elements in the array like you can in C because they are stored contiguously always. But that is not possible. Yes you can pass in a pointer to an element in the array as you show, but in your function you don't do anything with the rest of the array, because js can't do something like that. He wants to pass in a pointer to array[6] and in the function continue on to array[7] and array[8] and so on.